# Reverse engineer binary code in C programming (modify the memory address)

Tags: c

I am using ghex to modify the memory address. I want to change the call in main function instead of calling 1149  I want to call 1166 .
What is the hex value for 0000000000001149 ? so I can replace it.
Any idea?

0000000000001149 <aaa>:

```
1149:   55                      push   %rbp
114a:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
114d:   48 8d 05 b0 0e 00 00    lea    0xeb0(%rip),%rax        # 2004 <_IO_stdin_used+0x4>
1154:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
1157:   e8 d4 fe ff ff          call   1030 <puts@plt>
115c:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
1161:   e8 da fe ff ff          call   1040 <exit@plt>
```

0000000000001166 <bbb>:

```
1166:   55                      push   %rbp
1167:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
116a:   48 8d 05 a8 0e 00 00    lea    0xea8(%rip),%rax        # 2019 <_IO_stdin_used+0x19>
1171:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
1174:   e8 b7 fe ff ff          call   1030 <puts@plt>
1179:   bf 02 00 00 00          mov    $0x2,%edi
117e:   e8 bd fe ff ff          call   1040 <exit@plt>
```

0000000000001183 <main>:

```
1183:   55                      push   %rbp
1184:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
1187:   48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
118b:   89 7d fc                mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
118e:   48 89 75 f0             mov    %rsi,-0x10(%rbp)
1192:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
1197:   e8 ad ff ff ff          call   1149 <aaa>
119c:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
11a1:   e8 c0 ff ff ff          call   1166 <bbb>
11a6:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
11ab:   c9                      leave  
11ac:   c3                      ret    
11ad:   0f 1f 00                nopl   (%rax)
```

Comment: I think you'll have to make the hex on the line starting 1197 match the hex on the line starting 11a1.  The value to the right of `e8` is a relocation symbol/address, rather than the raw hex address of the function to be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values following the `e8` in the `call` instructions are offsets, so to change the call at 1197 to `call 1166`, you'll have to change the byte at 1198 from `ad` to  `ca`. This is because `119c` (the address after the call instruction) `+ ffffffca` (which is the same as `- 36` in 2's complement arithmatic) `= 1166`.

Comment: Thank you so much works perfect. I have an other help (SEE ABOVE) please look at it if you could. much appreciated it